# How can I add commas to numbers in PHP (Session Value)

Tags: php

I would like to change this:

```
4000
```

to this

```
4,000
```

I am using this code

```
<?php echo number_format(($_SESSION["result"]),",")  ; ?>
```

But its printing nothing...

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION["result"]`?

Comment: @MarkBaker Obviously `4000`...

Comment: i want to print 4000 as 4,000

Comment: @arkascha - Is it really so obvious? How many of the answers here on SO are related to silly typos? Case sensitivity, etc?

Comment: yes @arkascha  you are right

Comment: I suggest you start reading the documentation of functions you use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php Everything is explained in there and you get good examples on top.

Comment: I am a novice.

I need help

Comment: No. You need to read the documentation. If you have a specific question, _then_ is the time to ask here. After you read the documentation.

Comment: Please give me answer. I have already read this

Comment: @VivekSaha Check the answer below

Comment: If you had error reporting enabled, you'd see `PHP Warning:  number_format() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/c1FDQP/prog.php on line 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the parameters [shown here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
<?php echo number_format(($_SESSION["result"]), 3,",", "."); ?>
```

Comment: The thousands separator is actually the 4th argument, decimal separator is the 3rd: `<?php echo number_format(($_SESSION["result"]), 0, ".", ","); ?>`

Comment: @MarkBaker You're right, I only wanted to show he should enter a number in the 2nd parameter and forgot to add the 4th. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) or [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Example 01

```
$number = 1234.56;

//setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
//output -  USD 1,234.56
```

Example 02

```
 // number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," );
number_format($number, 0, ".", ",");
//output -  1,234.56
```

Comment: remove this `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');`

Comment: Whenever i am removing this
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');

its not working

Comment: number_format($_SESSION["result"],2,'.',',');

I am using this
But its not working

Comment: echo session and check data exist

Comment: @VivekSaha its working. No any errors come to this !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this It will give you the rupees in Indian format

```
function makecomma($input)
{
if(strlen($input)<=2)
{ return $input; }
$length=substr($input,0,strlen($input)-2);
$formatted_input = makecomma($length).",".substr($input,-2);
return $formatted_input;
}
function formatInIndianStyle($num){
$pos = strpos((string)$num, ".");
if ($pos === false) { $decimalpart="00";}
else { $decimalpart= substr($num, $pos+1, 2); $num = substr($num,0,$pos); }

if(strlen($num)>3 & strlen($num) <= 12){
            $last3digits = substr($num, -3 );
            $numexceptlastdigits = substr($num, 0, -3 );
            $formatted = makecomma($numexceptlastdigits);
            $stringtoreturn = $formatted.",".$last3digits.".".$decimalpart ;
}elseif(strlen($num)<=3){
            $stringtoreturn = $num.".".$decimalpart ;
}elseif(strlen($num)>12){
            $stringtoreturn = number_format($num, 2);
}

if(substr($stringtoreturn,0,2)=="-,"){$stringtoreturn = "-".substr($stringtoreturn,2 );}
$stringtoreturn=str_replace(".00","",$stringtoreturn);
return $stringtoreturn;
```

}

```
//You simply call this
echo formatInIndianStyle("4000");
```